# Convert value to NA based on column value

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L), Smoking.Status = c("Never", 
"Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Obviously, it doesn't make sense for this user to be both a never smoker and a smoker. How can I convert this individual to 'NA'?

I have a few individuals like this, so I would rather not manually convert user 123 to NA.

Comment: I get the following error message `Caused by error in `na_if()`:
! Can't convert `y` <logical> to match type of `x` <character>.`

Comment: Sorry, use `test %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Smoking.Status = ifelse(all(c('Never', 'Yes') %in% Smoking.Status), NA, Smoking.Status))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I added another ID to your data for testing:

```r
   ID Smoking.Status
1 123          Never
2 123            Yes
3 124            Yes
4 124            Yes
```

#### base R method:

```r
make_na <- vapply(split(dat$Smoking.Status, dat$ID), \(x) !length(setdiff(c("Never", "Yes"), x)), logical(1))
within(
    dat,
    Smoking.Status[make_na[as.character(dat$ID)]] <- NA_character_
)

#    ID Smoking.Status
# 1 123           <NA>
# 2 123           <NA>
# 3 124            Yes
# 4 124            Yes
```

#### `dplyr` approach

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
    group_by(ID) |>
    mutate(
        make_na = !length(setdiff(c("Never", "Yes"), Smoking.Status)),
        Smoking.Status = ifelse(make_na, NA_character_, Smoking.Status)
    ) |>
    select(-make_na)

# # A tibble: 4 × 2
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#      ID Smoking.Status
#   <int> <chr>         
# 1   123 NA            
# 2   123 NA            
# 3   124 Yes           
# 4   124 Yes
```

#### `data.table` method

For completeness, if you are using `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, make_na := !length(setdiff(c("Never", "Yes"), Smoking.Status)), ID]
dat[(make_na), Smoking.Status := NA_character_][, make_na := NULL]

#       ID Smoking.Status
#    <int>         <char>
# 1:   123           <NA>
# 2:   123           <NA>
# 3:   124            Yes
# 4:   124            Yes
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 124L, 124L), Smoking.Status = c("Never", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```